# событие на клик по radio

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть радио кнопка

```
<input type="radio" name="option[]" id="radio1" value="3">
```

как сделать событие на клик или чеккед

просто на обычную кнопку у меня вот так, а как на радио не выходит никак

```
 radio1.click = function(){
 alert("sdf);
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#radio1").change(function(){
    // твой код тут
});
```

Answer (score 0):

или без `JQ`

```
document.getElementById('#radio1').onchange = () => {
// твой код тут
};
```